# How to kill another Application or Activity programmatically without being root

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin, pid, kill-process

I want to kill another app from my Application once the other app comes into foreground.

I am already capturing if my app is in foreground or background. When my app gets to background, I want to filter for the right process by it's name and use its **pid** to kill it. I'm using `ActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses()` and filtering the processes for the wanted name, but only processes related to my app are shown. That's the first problem, because I cannot access the pid of the other apps processes.

The next problem is that, even by using the current **pid** (from adb) of the other apps process, my code which should kill it does not work (the other app keeps running).

I am using
 `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />` and  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />`.

I assume that I would need be root to kill other apps, so also something like `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(arrayOf<String>("su", "-c", "kill 24043"))` does not work.

```
val amg = getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
var processes = amg.getRunningAppProcesses();
for (info in processes) {
    if (info.processName.equals(otherAppName)) {
        val process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(arrayOf<String>("su", "-c", "kill $pid"))

        android.os.Process.killProcess(info.pid)
        android.os.Process.sendSignal(info.pid, android.os.Process.SIGNAL_KILL)
        amg.killBackgroundProcesses(info.processName)
    }
}
```

The last three lines result in the signal being send, but nothing happening and the one before obviously leads to `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "su": error=13, Permission denied`.

Is there another way to kill another app, that doesn't require to be root?

Comment: Short answer to your question is "no".

Answer (score 1):

You can't kill another app for security reasons. As a user, i don't want to install an app that close my apps without a good reason and without I even know about it, it would be pretty weird. That being said, it's possible to close background process from another app's, I didn't test it by myself but here is:

```
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
manager.killBackgroundProcesses(packageName);
```

You'll need to put this on your Manifest as well:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
```